# Turn user input strings into a function call

Tags: function, python-2.7, user-input

I am in the process of writing a lexer for a text based game.  A simplified example of what my code looks like this:

```
class Character:
    def goWest(self, location):
        self.location == location.getWest() #getWest() would be defined in the location class
x = raw_input("What action would you like to take")
```

With this code, I would like the player to enter something like: "Go West" and have a separate function take the substring "West", and then call the goWest() method for that Character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multiple `if` statements:

```
x = raw_input("What action would you like to take")
direction = x.split()[-1].lower()
if direction == "west":
    character.goWest(location)
elif direction == "east":
    character.goEast(location)
elif direction == "north":
    character.goNorth(location)
else:
    character.goSouth(location)
```

Alternatively, you could alter your `go` function:

```
class Character:
    def go(self, direction, location):
        self.location = location
        self.direction = direction
        #call code based on direction
```

And go about the above as:

```
x = raw_input("What action would you like to take")
character.go(x.split()[-1].lower(), location)
```

You could use `exec`, but `exec` and `eval` are very dangerous.

Once you have functions `goWest()`, `goEast()`, `goNorth()`, and `goSouth()`:

```
>>> func = "go"+x.split()[-1]+"()" #"goWest()"
>>> exec(func)
west
```

Comment: Would there be an alternative method because my game could involve many more actions than just directions, and writing so many if statements would be difficult.